# How can I implement WorkManager within an Activity instead of a separate class so I can use Activity variables?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-workmanager

I want to use most of the variables from my activity in the WorkManager to be able to send notifications even when the user is not on the app. How can I use the variables from my activity in my WorkManager to generate notifications using those variables?

```
public class UploadTask extends Worker {
    public static Context context;
    public static final String FLIGHT_NUMBER="";
    public static  final String DEPARTURE_DATE = "";
    private FlightRepository repository;

    public UploadTask(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Worker.Result doWork() {

String catering = getInputData().getString(CATERING);

String flightnumber = getInputData().getString(FLIGHT_NUMBER);
        String departuredate = getInputData().getString(DEPARTURE_DATE);
        System.out.println("flightnumber"+ flightnumber); //it prints departure date here, why?
        

        Flight flight = repository.getFlight(flightnumber,departuredate);

        String catering = flight.getCatering_start_time();

        createNotificationChannel();
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "firstNotif")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("Started at " + catering)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

        notificationManager.notify(110, builder.build());


        return Worker.Result.success();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            CharSequence name = "channel";
            String description = "Notif Channel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("firstNotif",name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
           notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

}
```

**Within my activity**

```
UploadTask.context = FlightDescriptionActivity.this;
PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(UploadTask.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .setInputData(new Data.Builder()
                            .putString(UploadTask.FLIGHT_NUMBER, flightNumber)
                            .putString(UploadTask.DEPARTURE_DATE, departure_date)
                            .build())
                    .build();
            WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);
```

Below is the code to my repository.
**Repository**

```
public class FlightRepository {

    private FlightDao flightDao;
    private LiveData<List<Flight>> allFlights;

    public FlightRepository(Application application) {
        FlightDatabase database = FlightDatabase.getInstance(application);
        flightDao = database.flightDao();
        allFlights = flightDao.getAllFlights();

    }

    public void insert(Flight flight) {
        new InsertFlightAsyncTask(flightDao).execute(flight);
    }

    public void update(Flight flight) {
        new UpdateFlightAsyncTask(flightDao).execute(flight);
    }

    public void delete(Flight flight) {
        new DeleteFlightAsyncTask(flightDao).execute(flight);
    }

    public void deleteAllFlights() {
        new DeleteAllFlightsAsyncTask(flightDao).execute();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Flight>> getAllFlights() {
        return allFlights;
    }

    public Flight getFlight(String flightNumber, String date){
        return flightDao.getFlight(flightNumber,date);
    }

    public boolean existsFlight(String flightNumber, String date){
        return flightDao.existsFlight(flightNumber, date);
    }
}
```

How do I initialise this in my `Worker` class?

Comment: That is not practical. There is no guarantee that your activity will exist at the time the work is being done.

Comment: @CommonsWare so if i want to use variables from my activity in the notification, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: I have no idea what these variables are. When you create your `WorkRequest` via a `Builder`, use `setInputData()` to provide the data that your `Worker` will use to do the work. In [this Java sample](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v2.0/DownloadWork) and [its Kotlin counterpart](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v2.0/DownloadWork), I pass a URL to download this way.

Comment: @CommonsWare By variables, I mean the data used on my Activity. Can I pass it to my Worker class as a parameter ?

Comment: Use `setInputData()` on your `WorkRequest.Builder`, as I noted in my previous comment.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have uploaded the code above to include `setInputData()`, however, it always shows me the default one i.e. 18:00 in the notification, even thought I am passing the catering variable in my `WorkRequest.Builder`. What can be going wrong?

Comment: You do not appear to be reading the input data in your `Worker`. Call `getInputData()` and read the value to use.

Comment: When I call `getInputData()` in my `Worker`, it seems to be taking the outdated variable which was initialised in my onCreate method in my activity the first time. It does not send the updated variable when I update it on my activity after say 15 minutes. I have updated the code above with the `getInputData()` as well

Comment: That is to be expected. The data is being copied at the time you are calling `putString(UploadTask.CATERING, catering_start).build())`. Either do not change the value, or do not schedule the work until you have the correct value, or cancel the work and reschedule it when the value changes, or store the value on disk (`SharedPreferences`, `DataStore`, SQLite, ordinary file, etc.) as it changes and have your `Worker` load the value from there.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need to change the value, as I get the input from the user and hence need to pass in the updated data. I am storing in Rooms database so I can retrieve it. How can I reschedule when the value changes?

Comment: @CommonsWare I do read the updated value from the database on onCreate()

Comment: @CommonsWare to give you some context, when the user presses a button on my app, the catering time is recorded and then I want that time to be sent as a notification to the user later. I am recording the time in the Rooms database, and when I read it on the application it shows me the updated time, however still the old time stamp is sent to the `Worker` class. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have your `Worker` read the value from your database.

Comment: @CommonsWare In order to query the database, I need the flight number and departure date, which are in my activity. I am passing it using `setInputData()`, however it only reads the departure date once and rest of the time it is null.

Comment: I have updated the code in the question

Comment: @CommonsWare `flightViewModel = new ViewModelProvider((context)).get(FlightViewModel.class);` It doesn't allow me to specify `context` there, hence how do I initialise my database's viewmodel here?

Comment: A database does not have a viewmodel. An activity or a fragment has a viewmodel. Your `Worker` accesses your database, directly or through a repository (if you are using the repository pattern).

Comment: I do have a repository because  I am using MVVM architecture, so how can i initialise using the repository here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229267/discussion-between-ian-bell-and-commonsware).

Comment: @CommonsWare `Flight flight = repository.getFlight(flightnumber,departuredate);` I tried this, however, it gives me an error  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.example.myapplication.Flight com.example.myapplicatio.FlightRepository.getFlight(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @CommonsWare how can I access the repository directly via the `Worker`. I have updated the code above.

Comment: @CommonsWare `System.out.println("flightnumber"+ flightnumber);` here sometimes it prints the flightnumber, sometimes departure date and sometimes null. How can i just make it print the flight number. From my activity when I pass the data, it always passes as flight number, however in `Worker` it randomly prints anything.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am extremely stuck here, I'd really appreciate your help on this one

Comment: Your `NullPointerException` is because you are not assigning a value to `repository`. I have no way of knowing where your repository comes from. And for the rest, I have no idea.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added in my Repository class code in the question now.

Comment: @CommonsWare how can I initialise the repository given the `Worker` and `Repository` code above?

Comment: @CommonsWare why do I get the data as null in my `Worker` class sometimes?